# Is there out of box support to use OAuth2 based Bearer token with Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is  there out of box support to use OAuth2 based Bearer token with Apache HttpClient? I know we can just pass it in headers, but my worry is to handle token such that it is re fetched before it expires.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with Apache HttpClient, but if you're using SpringBoot there is OAuth2RestTemplate which automates everything with bearer tokens

Comment: Thanks @stream28 for suggesting that. Actually I am in doubt whether to use it after reading it's doc that RestTemplate will be deprecated in future. This is the Note from RestTemplate doc:  " The RestTemplate will be deprecated in a future version and will not have major new features added going forward. See the WebClient section of the Spring Framework reference documentation for more details and example code. "

Comment: Update: Now I am successfully using Spring WebClient (as it is the recommended approach) to post requests with OOTB OAuth2 support. There is one Stackoverflow post suggesting the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/59247804/2806640